# Получение метаинфы из файла изображения

Tags: c++, opencv, обработка-изображений

Меня интересует как можно получить из файла изображения метаинфу (в частности размеры изображения) не прибегая к загрузки всего файла? К примеру, в программе имеется функция, которой нужно знать размер изображения (в пикселях) которое лежит в определенном файле. На данный момент я загружаю (средствами opencv) этот файл и смотрю размеры матрицы, что не очень разумно (скорость, расход памяти).

PS хранить размер изображения отдельно не является приемлемым вариантом

Comment: А какой тип файла? В соответствии с форматом (jpg, png and etc) метаданные хранятся в начале файла. Можно прочитать только их. Вот пример для png https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354459/c-how-to-get-the-image-size-of-a-png-file-in-directory

Comment: @becouse файлы png и jpg - только эти форматы

Comment: Пример для png я приложил.